# Confused about Eigen QR decomposition

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen, eigen3, eigenvalue

I am confused about Eigen's QR decomposition. My understanding is that the matrix `Q` is stored implicitly as a sequence of Householder transformations, and that the matrix `R` is stored as an upper triangular matrix, and that the diagonal of `R` contains the eigenvalues of `A` (at least up to phase, which is all I care about).

However, I wrote the following program which computes the eigenvalues of a matrix `A` via two different methods, one using the `Eigen::EigenSolver`, and the other using `QR`. I know that my `QR` method is returning the wrong results, and that the `EigenSolver` method is returning the correct results.

What am I misunderstanding here?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main()
{
    using Real = long double;
    long n = 2;
    Eigen::Matrix<Real, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> A(n,n);

    for(long i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (long j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            A(i,j) = Real(1)/Real(i+j+1);
        }
    }

    auto QR = A.householderQr();

    auto Rdiag = QR.matrixQR().diagonal().cwiseAbs();
    auto [min, max] = std::minmax_element(Rdiag.begin(), Rdiag.end());
    std::cout << "\u03BA\u2082(A) = " << (*max)/(*min) << "\n";

    std::cout << "\u2016A\u2016\u2082 via QR = " << (*max) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Diagonal of R =\n" << Rdiag << "\n";


    // dblcheck:

    Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver<decltype(A)> eigensolver(A);
    if (eigensolver.info() != Eigen::Success) {
        std::cout << "Something went wrong.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    auto absolute_eigs = eigensolver.eigenvalues().cwiseAbs();
    auto [min1, max1] = std::minmax_element(absolute_eigs.begin(), absolute_eigs.end());
    std::cout << "\u03BA\u2082(A) via eigensolver = " << (*max1)/(*min1) << "\n";
    std::cout << "\u2016A\u2016\u2082 via eigensolver = " << (*max1) << "\n";
    std::cout << "The absolute eigenvalues of A via eigensolver are:\n" << absolute_eigs << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```sh
κ₂(A) = 15
‖A‖₂ via QR = 1.11803
Diagonal of R =
  1.11803
0.0745356
κ₂(A) via eigensolver = 19.2815
‖A‖₂ via eigensolver = 1.26759
The absolute eigenvalues of A via eigensolver are:
0.0657415
  1.26759
```

Other info:

- Cloned eigen from the head:

```sh
$ hg log | more
changeset:   11993:20cbc6576426
tag:         tip
date:        Tue May 07 16:44:55 2019 -0700
summary:     Fix AVX512 & GCC 6.3 compilation
```

- Occurs when compiled with g++-8, g++-9, and Apple Clang, with and without `-ffast-math`. I obtain the same wrong result with `Eigen::FullPivHouseholderQR`.
- I also looked into the source `HouseholderQR.h`, and they compute the determinant via `m_qr.diagonal().prod()`, which makes me feel somewhat more confident that I'm using the API correctly. Taking the product of the eigenvalues from the EigenSolver returns the same values as `QR.absDeterminant()`.
- The following code snippet *does not return the original matrix A*:

```cpp
Eigen::Matrix<Real, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> R = QR.matrixQR();
Eigen::Matrix<Real, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> Q = QR.householderQ();
std::cout << "Q*R = \n" << Q*R << "\n";
```

- I checked that `Q` has all the requisite properties: Q^-1 = Q^T, Q^TQ = I, and |det(Q)| = 1.
- I've also verified that `QR.householderQ().transpose()*QR.matrixQR()` is not equal `A`; although one column is correct and another is wrong.

Comment: I don't know Eigen. But QR decomposition doesn't give you the eigenvalues. It needs further processing to get eigenvalues from QR decomposition. It's just the case that the product of diagonal is the determinant (because R is triangular, and Q has a determinant of plus/minus one).

Comment: @geza: You're right. Probably ought to delete this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @geza pointed out, the `R` matrix of a QR decomposition will (in general) not contain the Eigenvalues of the original matrix, life would be too easy if that was the case :)

To your other problem, if you want to reconstruct `A` from `Q` and `R` you need to only look at the upper triangular part of `QR.matrixQR()`

```
Eigen::Matrix<Real, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>
              R = QR.matrixQR().triangularView<Eigen::Upper>();
```

Besides that, I'd suggest being careful with using `auto` in combination with expression-templates (nothing severely wrong in your case, except that `Rdiag` is evaluated at least twice).

Also, using `long double` is barely a good idea on modern CPUs. First make sure that the algorithms you use are numerically stable and if precision really is an issue, consider using arbitrary precision floats (like MPFR).